# std::function and Signal/Slot system

Tags: c++, c++11, signals, signals-slots, std-function

I'm trying to create a simple Signals/Slots system in C++ without boost but I've got some problems when I try to use it with parameters, here is my code :

**My Signal class :**

```
template <typename T> 
class Signal
{
private:
    typedef std::function<T> Slot;

public:
    Signal();

    void connect( Slot slot );
    void emit( T data );
    void emit();

private:    
    std::vector<Slot> slots;    
};
```

**My Test class :**

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object();
    void sayHello(  int i  );
};
```

So, I use my class like that :

```
Signal<void(int)> signal;
signal.connect( std::bind( &Object::sayHello, player, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
signal.emit( 0 );
```

I've got a warning in Signal.cpp : 
**Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (*)(int)' to 'int' for 1st argument;**

In this code :

```
template <typename T>
void Signal<T>::emit( T data )
{
    typename std::vector<Slot>::iterator i;
    Slot t;

    for( i = this->slots.begin(); i != this->slots.end(); i++ )
    {
        t = (*i);
        t( data );   // Here
    }
}
```

How can I solve that? If I want give an object or multiples parameters to my "emit" method, hoc can i do?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2d733163b1af460eedcf05a7fb760608) what you were trying for? You're specifying that `T` == `void(int)`, but `emit` seems to expect that `T` == `int`.

Comment: Oups! Thanks, that work better with that indeed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Picking three lines from your `Signal` class:

```
template <typename T> 
    // ...
    typedef std::function<T> Slot;
    // ...
    void emit( T data );
```

And the declaration of your signal:

```
Signal<void(int)> signal;
```

The answer should be pretty obvious: `void emit(T)` becomes `void emit(void(*)(int))` (function types like `void(int)` transform to pointers when they are function parameters).

I'd simply recommend going the same way every class template that uses `T<Signature>` goes: partial specialization.

```
template<class Sig>
class Signal;

template<class R, class... Args>
class Signal<R(Args...)>{
  // ...
  typedef std::function<R(Args...)> Slot;
  // ...
  void emit(Args... args) const{
    // iterate over slots and call them, passing `args...`
  }
};
```

Comment: `emit` doesn't seem to use the return type for anything anyway, so maybe `void` should be assumed?

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm still pondering what the best course of action would be here. Assuming `void` is one of them, but doesn't change my answer by much. I'm also thinking about a combinator parameter that is optionally passed to `emit` and either combines the result values (like folding) or passes them on to somewhere.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've learnt many things here and that work perfectly :D. I will read more about variables args with template in c++ so.